# What is the difference between the navigate function and routerLink in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm following the official [Angular 2 tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html#!#update-the-_heroescomponent_-class) and it uses the navigate function in a very similar way as the routerLink. What is the difference between them? Which to use when?

```
this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedHero.id]);
```

---

```
[routerLink]="['/detail', hero.id]"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[routerLink]` is an Angular directive that you can use in html for `<a>` or `<button>` elements. The directive will listen for click events and navigate to the path created with `params` provided to `routerLink`.

`this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedHero.id]);` is used in your component or service to navigate.

`routerLink` directive and `this.router.navigate` should navigate to exactly the same url if the same arguments are specified.

Comment: `routerLink` works on any element, not only on `<a>` and `<button>`. Another main difference is, that for relative navigation, you need to pass the route to the `relativeTo` parameter with `this.router.navigate()` to make clear relative to what route the navigation should happen, while the `routerLink` automatically passes the current route as `relativeTo`.

Comment: also using the navigate method allows you to execute other code on change of route, eg unsubscribing to observables, tidying up, storing state etc

Comment: You are right that routerLink works on any element but think about accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

`routerLink` is a directive that behind the scenes uses `router.navigate()` 
as well.

The value of `routerLink` and the function-argument in `navigate` is exactly the same.